# Tags vs Tagging on Meta

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms, meta

Here on Meta GD, there are both [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) and [tagging](/questions/tagged/tagging). On both MSE and MSO (and probably others as well, but I didn't check), [tagging](/questions/tagged/tagging) is a synonym of [tags](/questions/tagged/tags), so that should probably be applied here as well, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I synonymised them. Thanks for spotting.

Comment: Thanks! I copied over the tag wiki from [meta-tag:tagging] to [meta-tag:tags], since [meta-tag:tags] didn't have any yet.